# ajax call: Sometimes, _POST is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a page with an ajax call that I build based on user choices. In some cases, it works as expected. In others, the target page doesn't receive the _POST items I pass.

Here's the key portion of the page:

```
var filters = getFilters();
var fnargs = "GetArticles|" + filters ;

$.ajax({
    url: 'retrievedata.php',
    type: "POST",
    async:true,
    data: {"functionname":"getpapers", "arguments":fnargs},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (obj) {

                  if( (obj.error != '') ) { 
                   if (obj.length == 0) {
                       $("#message").text("No articles match your choices. Showing previous list of articles.");
                   }
                   else {
                        $("#message").empty();
                        ArticleTable = '';
                        for (line=0; line<obj.length; line++) {
                            ArticleTable += "<tr><td>";
                            ArticleTable += "<a href='" + obj[line].URL + "' target='_blank'>";
                            ArticleTable += obj[line].Title;
                            ArticleTable += "</a>";
                            ArticleTable += "</td>";
                            ArticleTable += "<td>" + obj[line].Publication + "</td>";
                            ArticleTable += "<td>" + obj[line].PubDate + "</td>";
                            ArticleTable += "<td>" + obj[line].ArticleType + "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        //console.log(ArticleTable);
                        $("#articles tbody").html(ArticleTable);
                        $("#articles").trigger("update",true);
                   }
                  }
                  else {
                    $("#testresult").text("Error");
                  }
                  success = true;
            },
     error: function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
         success = false;
         $("#testresult").text('Error occurred: '.textStatus);
     }            
    })
```

retrievedata.php begins like this (I added var_dump for debugging, of course):

```
$aResult = array();
$returnval = 'at start';
var_dump($_POST);
if( !isset($_POST['functionname']) ) { 
    $aResult['error'] = 'No function name!'; 
    $returnval = 'No function name!';
    }

if( !isset($_POST['arguments']) ) { 
    $aResult['error'] = 'No function arguments!'; 
    $returnval = 'No function arguments!';
    }
```

(dbfns.php is a set of functions for talking to SQL Server, and not relevant to the problem.)

getFilters returns a comma-separated string containing 3 shorter strings. It could be something like:

```
'1','3,6','2015'
```

or it could be 3 empty strings:

```
'','',''
```

or some could be empty and others populated:

```
'1','',''
```

No matter what values I pass, the Network tab of Firefox's Web Console shows me that the correct parameters have been assembled. For example, for that last case, I see this in the Params tab:

```
functionname:"getpapers"
arguments:"GetArticles|'1','',''"
```

But the response from the retrievedata page is this:

```
array(0) {
}
No function arguments!
```

That is, it's not receiving the _POST data. But that doesn't always happen. For example, if getFilters returns this string:

```
'','','1999'
```

then the Network tab shows me this:

```
functionname:"getpapers"
arguments:"GetArticles|'','','1999'"
```

and retrievedata gives me this response (along with the actual data the page is meant to retrieve):

```
array(2) {
  ["functionname"]=>
  string(9) "getpapers"
  ["arguments"]=>
  string(24) "GetArticles|'','','1999'"
}
```

I can't see why the difference in the value returned by getFilters is having this effect.

EDIT: User @Davis had me check and it turns out that in the cases that don't work, my POST is changing into a GET. Any ideas why that would happen?

Comment: Can you add in the rest of the `$.ajax()` call? I would like to see how you have the handler setup for the return. This sounds like your code is acting on the response before it actually gets it.

Comment: If you output `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` does it change from `post` to `get` for the times it doesn't work?

Comment: @Davis, bingo! That's exactly what's happening. Any idea why or how to stop it?

Comment: Well, the only time I encountered this it was doing a redirect I wasn't expecting. It was happening in `.htaccess` for me. But, that wouldn't explain why it works for you sometimes and not other times.

Comment: Since the focus of the question has changed, I've reposted it targeting the POST v. GET question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930618/ajax-call-sometimes-changes-from-post-to-get

Comment: Just discovered that $_GET is empty in retrievedata.php, just like $_POST.

Comment: It turned out that the empty $_POST was a red herring. The real problem was that the results coming back from the database weren't UTF-8, plus there were some error-handler issues.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are posting the `JSON` as the body of the request as opposed to a post variable.

Here is how you retrieve the posted `JSON`

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

That is just the string, you will need to decode before parsing

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data);
```

Comment: no.... that's not at all what is happening. Objects get converted to param strings, not json.

Comment: @KevinB believe me, php does not parse json automatlically

Comment: he isn't sending json to php. he's sending post params. jquery doesn't convert objects to json. it never has and likely never will.