# ajax call sometimes changes from POST to GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page with an ajax call based on user choices. In some cases, though it's specified as POST, it gets changed to GET; as a result, the code in the called page fails.

EDIT: Although $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] tells me it's a GET, in the response page, the $_GET variable is empty, just like the $_POST variable. (I was hoping I could work around the problem by grabbing the params from the $_GET instead.)

Here's the relevant portion of the ajax call:

```
var filters = getFilters();
var fnargs = "GetArticles|" + filters ;

$.ajax({
    url: 'retrievedata.php',
    type: "POST",
    async:true,
    data: {"functionname":"getpapers", "arguments":fnargs},
    dataType: "JSON",
```

It's followed by success and error sections.

The getFilters function builds a comma-separated string containing 3 shorter strings. Any one of them or all of them can be empty. When populated, each is a comma-separated list of integers. Here are some examples:

```
'1','3,6','2015'
'','',''
'1','',''
```

In every case, the Network tab of Firefox's Web Console shows me that the correct parameters have been assembled for the call, and for that matter, that it's a POST. But I added a check of $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] in retrievedata.php (the called page) and I find that some of the time, the POST has become a GET.

This happens consistently in the sense that the same getFilters result is always treated the same way. But beyond that, the only consistency I can find is that if the third string is populated, it always works. Here are some cases where it works:

```
'','','1998'
'','','1998,2008'
'','1',''
'','2,1',''
'','2',''
'1','','1999'
'1','1','1999'
'1','1',''
'1,3','1',''
'3','',''
```

Here are some where it changes to GET:

```
'','',''
'','3,1',''
'','2,3',''
'','3',''
'1','',''
'1,3','',''
```

Probably should note that I posted the original problem at [ajax call: Sometimes, _POST is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908301/ajax-call-sometimes-post-is-empty). Thanks to a commenter there, I figured out that the change to GET was the key issue.

Also, worth adding that I have another page with a virtually identical call, except that its version of getFilters concatenates only two comma-separated strings (and the first component of fnargs is "GetPapers" rather than "GetArticles". That page always makes the right call.

Comment: If you're looking at your network tab and it's a POST, but the server says it's a get, that's a server-side/network problem.

Comment: Contacted my host (GoDaddy) and they're digging to see if it's something on their side.

Comment: GoDaddy says they can't help. Suggested I look at server logs. In those, I see error 500.0 in the failed cases, which seems to be "Module or ISAPI error occurred." They also suggest that I should move from MSSQL/Windows to MySQL/Linux. Thoughts?

Comment: non-managed server, right? i wouldn't expect them to be able to help you with a non-managed server. Moving to another is also unlikely to solve the underlying problem directly.

Comment: Shared hosting. Their take is that PHP on Windows is buggy, so I should switch to Linux.

Comment: php on windows is inefficient, and can be buggy, but won't have the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the symptom of appearing to switch from POST to GET was a red herring (possibly due to issues in the error handler code). The real problem here was that some of the data was coming back with characters that json_encode() couldn't handle. Setting the database connection to UTF-8 fixed it.